# React-Router make my Navbar disappear, but without it in the code, everything is fine

Tags: reactjs, react-router

i have a problem. When i add router into code, it makes my Navbar disappear, there is only white web page left. When i take it out of my code, everything is fine. No errors in terminal.

```
import { BrowserRouter as Route, Routes, Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import Home from '../Pages/Home';
import About from '../Pages/About';
import Contacts from '../Pages/Contacts';
import Blog from '../Pages/Blog';

<BrowserRouter>
    <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Home/>} exact/>
        <Route path="/about" element={<About/>} exact/>
        <Route path="/contacts" element={<Contacts/>} exact/>
        <Route path="/blog" element={<Blog/>} exact/>
    </Routes>
</BrowserRouter>
```

What i did wrong? (React Router v6)

Comment: It's unclear why you expected a nav bar... where is it?

Comment: Where is the navbar?

Comment: It's unclear where any navbar is being rendered, but you've a typo in the `react-router-dom` imports. `BrowserRouter` is being imported as a `Route`. Fix the imports and the code should run without issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom'
```

update your imports to look like above

Answer (score 0):

import your Nav component and place it right after opening BrowserRouter tag. Do not place Nav inside Routes, because you will see white screen as well